# Learning Python: implementing a virtual method

Tags: python

First day learning Python, please excuse the basic question.

Assuming I have been given an object which contains an unimplemented method that I need to implement, e.g:

```
class myclass():
  def __init__(self)
    self.unimplementedmethod = False
```

What is the correct way to implement this in an instantiated object?  I do not want to alter the base class in any way.
I have experimented and found the following code seems to work, but is it correct/good style?

```
def methodimplementation():
  print("method called")

myobject = myclass()
myobject.unimplementedmethod=methodimplementation
```

Is this the right path?  Or should I be doing something different like perhaps creating a derived class first, implementing the methods in it, and then instantiating an object based on the derived class? What is best practice?

Comment: You should be subclassing the class, yes. And an unimplemented method shouldn't have the value `False`, but instead (if they exist) should be actual methods returning the singleton `NotImplemented`.

Comment: Thankyou.  This is from the open source project "Printrun". P.S Damn fast!

Comment: I know this is not a code review, but you don't need `()` in `class myclass():` (however, you should always subclass `object` if you're writing Python 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass the base class:

```
class myclass():
    def some_method():
        raise NotImplementedError

class my_subclass(myclass):
    def some_method():
        print("method called")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a [abstract base class](https://zaiste.net/2013/01/abstract_classes_in_python/). For that, you need to inherit [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) in your base class. Then defining the method as abstract, you need to decorate it with [`@abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod). For example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method():
        pass
```

Then you may create the child class as:

```
class MyChildClass(BaseClass):
    def my_method():
        print 'my method'
```

Answer (score 1):

The good way is using subclasses, but if you can't do it, here is a way to access to `self` from a simple function not defined in a class:

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        try:
            self._foo(self)
        except AttributeError:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def set_foo(self, function):
        setattr(self, '_foo', function)

    def another_method(self):
        print "Another method from {}".format(self)


def foo(self):
    self.another_method()

bar = Bar()
bar.set_foo(foo)

bar.foo()
```

So, `def foo(self)` define a function with a single argument `self`, like a method. This function call a instance method `another_method`.

`Bar.set_foo` create a new attribute `_foo` in instance of `Bar`.

Finally, `Bar.foo` try to access to `self._foo` with `self` as argument. If `_foo` is do not exists, `Bar.foo` will raise a NotImplementedError as expected.

Like it you can access to `self` from `foo` without subclasses.